# Can a controller inherit scope from a parent controller when using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following:

```
var admin = {

   name: 'admin',
    url: '/admin',
    views: {
        'nav-sub': {
            templateUrl: '/Content/app/admin/partials/nav-sub.html',
            controller: function ($scope) { $scope.message = "hello"; }
        }
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "hello";
    }]
}

var subject = {
    name: 'subject',
    parent: admin,
    url: '/subject',
    views: {
        'grid@': {
            templateUrl: '/Content/app/admin/partials/grid-subject.html',
            controller: 'AdminGridSubjectController',
        }
    }
};
```

I would like the AdminGridSubjectController to know what the $scope.message value is but it seems not to know anything about it. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
stApp.controller('AdminGridSubjectController', ['$scope', function ( $scope ) {
    var a = $scope.message;
}]);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to access the `scope` of a parent controller in Angular UI Router use:

```
$scope.$parent
```

Then the parent scope is then freely available to you.

Comment: This doesn't work for views. The child view cannot access the non-root scope properties of the parent that contains the view. They just don't exist and aren't exposed properly.

Comment: I have been looking for hours! thanx a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that the name should reflect the parent in it:

```
var subject = {
    name: 'admin.subject',
    parent: admin,
    url: '/subject',
    ...
```

Here's a complete illustration of how to inherit $scope with ui-router: [plunker ex](http://plnkr.co/edit/nmYj6798VllaV8pCYrWX?p=preview)

Comment: schwarts - Thanks Ben. I tried this but I still have the problem. I am wondering if this is something to do with the fact that I am using views.

Comment: @Anne It's the view's problem.

Comment: Shouldn't need that if you declare `parent`, right? Also, can you use a string instead of an object reference? Like, `{ ..., parent: 'admin', ... }`? Thx!

Comment: When using the dot notation there is no need to specify the parent. This is in the most recent ui-router. Probably different back then.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways (and workarounds) to access parent scope data ... but controller inheritance itself, is not possible: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views#what-do-child-states-inherit-from-parent-states